# How can I paste a selection to a pre-determined size in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Basically trying to eliminate white space borders of a scanned image.

I am able to select the image.

Now I want to paste it so that it fills an 8.5" x 11" page so that there is no white space?

Also, is there an easier way to eliminate borders?

Comment: What size is the original image? I'm just trying to understand why you don't want to use the crop tool.

Comment: Variable.  It's a form, so it just has a 1/2 white space border on all four sides of the printed area. Depending on how it's scanned it could be 8x10.5 or if it's scanned poorly maybe 7x10 etc.  I'm trying to standardize each image by selecting it, then pasting it to exactly 8.5x11

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm going to post an answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the scanned document in GIMP
2. Select the Crop tool
3. Choose "Fixed Aspect Ratio" from the first dropdown menu
4. Enter "8.5:11" as the Crop tool's fixed ratio
5. Drag a box around the text area of your document. The width and height will be constrained to a rectangle of ratio 8.5:11
6. You can reposition the selected crop area by dragging it from inside the box, if necessary
7. Once you are satisfied with your selected crop area, press Enter to apply the crop and remove the border.

Every document you apply these steps to will be standardized and cut to exactly the same shape when their margins are removed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question perfectly - unfortunately, I asked the wrong question.  Sorry!  Here is a better question describing what I really need to do. https://superuser.com/questions/1472118/how-can-i-resize-the-content-of-an-image-in-gimp-to-a-standard-size

Comment: Haha! I'll check out the new version!