# How can I resize the content of an image in GIMP to a standard size?

Tags: gimp

I'm working with scanned forms in GIMP. Though the form is the same, they are often scanned at different magnifications.

I would like to select the contents of the form (printed area excluding white space borders) and paste it to a uniform size (say 8.5x11"). So smaller images will be enlarged upon pasting and larger images will be shrunken to the proper size.

Selecting is easy to do using the "select by color" tool, but pasting in this "standardized way" is what I can't figure out.

Here is an example form:
[image: Exmple Form]

Also, this will eventually be automated (hopefully) through macros so I'm working under the assumption that If I can do this in the UI, it can be automated.

Comment: Just to clarify: will these scanned images be the correct aspect ratio (8.5x11), just the wrong size?

Comment: That is correct.  Sometimes they will be off center as well, but aspect ratio should be fairly correct.

Comment: The off-center content makes this a bit more complicated. If the content is off center in the original scan, would you want it to be centered in the final version by this automated solution? It's easy to center content manually but automating this would be tricky. Simple batch resizing to a standard size is quite straightforward, I just don't know how to solve the off-center content issue automatically.

Comment: They're generally not too far off center, so that's a second priority.

Comment: If centering the content isn't important and cropping the border isn't necessary, then solving the resizing component of this should be easy.

Comment: If you could include a couple of sample scans, with any sensitive information obscured, it would really help us to figure out what tools might work best. Being able to see the general layout of a form and what colors it has would be really useful when testing automation of the color selection tool etc.

Comment: If this is a task you have to do every week/month, I'd get your desired size & format added to the very top of the office instruction manual ;) After a couple of cycles where you can politely remind people to send the correct size, you can then just start rejecting them as 'not as specified'. There are some tasks you simply should not have to do. This is one of them.

Comment: Added an example form (this is just a downloaded template, but the forms I work with are similar in that they have a printed area, surrounded by white space.  They arrive at all different magnifications (with some shifting and skew also, but that's minor).  Our OCR software would like to see everything straight and uniform.  I'm trying to automate gimp to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I actually do something similar every month for my lunch expenses, with receipts of various formats.

- I take pictures of all the receipts using a fixed camera, so the receipts have a varying size inside the frame
- I mass-process the images in Gimp:

  - Crop tool to crop the image to the receipt (one mouse drag, one double-click). For your specific purpose you can set the crop tool to have a fixed ratio.
  - Save picture and load next in sequence (this is a single keystroke, once you ave installed the [`ofn-file-next` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) and set up a shortcut)

  This takes a few seconds per image, so you process a hundred images in 5 minutes.
- Once I have the cropped images on disk, I use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) in a shell script to set them all to the same size:

```
#! /bin/bash

dir=${1:-.}

for f in "$dir/"*.JPG; 
do
        echo "Processing $f"
        convert "$f" -resize 600x -sharpen 0x1.0 -quality 85 "$dir/$(basename "$f" .JPG).jpg"
done
```

Warning: the script above assumes that the input images are JPG, and that the filesystem is case-sensitive

ImageMagick is also available for Windows (but of course you have to adapt the script above for BAT or Powershell).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pasting, it may be simpler to just crop the image. Pasting by itself will not scale the image. Both Crop and Rectangle selection tools allow you to force a fixed aspect ratio that may help to scale the image  (that you will do with *Image>Scale image*).

Gimp works in pixels. The actual print size is fairly irrelevant. To print at a given size, you set an image definition (*Image>Print size*). Print size, pixels, and definition are inter-related: `pixels = print size * definition`. You cannot change one without changing at least one of the other two. Good quality print requires a minimum definition (around 300PPI), so for a fixed print size (8.5x11"), this means a minimum size in pixels (2550x3300).

Yes, it can be automated, but Gimp has no macros, only scripts.

Comment: GIMP has plugins which allow batch resizing.

Comment: The problem I see with cropping is how will GIMP actually find the printed area when automated? Seems like a manual process.  The color selection tool, on the other hand seems easier to automate, because it seems to grab the printed part of the form regardless of where I click on the image.  Am I understanding what you mean by cropping?